# How to post a "poster" to VKontakte social network wall

Tags: social-networking, vk

I have a script that can post a text or an image to the VK.com over API. But I can't find a way to create a *poaster*:

[image]

There is no information about posters at the official [documentation page](https://vk.com/dev/wall.post).

Comment: This question in russian language - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1117773/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-vk-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the parameter `poster_bkg_id = {background_number_for_poster}`. This parameter is not described in the [documentation](https://github.com/VBIralo/vk-posters) (thanks to the author [https://github.com/VBIralo/vk-posters](https://vk.com/dev/wall.post)).

### Backgrounds (poster_bkg_id)

- Gradients

  > 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
- Artwork

  > 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 31, 32
- Emoji Patterns

  > 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30